# Oracle: allow some JOBS to be controlled by every schema

Tags: oracle, jobs

I need to take offline and offline JOBS of schema B while I'm logged from schema A.

Can I reach this using some grants?

Comment: Which version of Oracle?  Are you using DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using DBMS_JOB then your options are limited.  According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_job.htm#1002115):

> "There are no database privileges associated with jobs. DBMS_JOB does
> not allow a user to touch any jobs except their own."

There is a workaround: DBMS_IJOB.  This is undocumented, because it is owned by SYS and isn't supposed to be used by real people.  You want to be careful with this.  As it is undocumented we're reliant on unofficial sources.  Adam Donahue wrote a useful blog on this package.  [Read it here](http://manageoracle.blogspot.co.uk/).

Alternatively, you can build your own infrastructure: schema B owns a hand-rolled package to manage their jobs and grants EXECUTE on that package to schema A.

DBMS_SCHEDULER (introduced in 10g) offers a bit more flexibility.  Well , actually a lot more flexibility, for which read "complexity".  There are various ways to slice and dice responsibilties with scheduled jobs, and a matrix of privileges and roles.  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schedover.htm#ADMIN033).

Out of the box there isn't a way to allow Schema A to manage all of Schema B's jobs.  There are various `ANY` level privileges associated with DBMS_SCHEDULER but those are pretty powerful and cannot be restricted to rights on a single schema.  At the crudest level B can simply do this:

```
 grant alter on bjob1 to A;
 grant alter on bjob2 to A;
```

and so on.  This will allow A to do most actions on B's jobs except stopping a running job.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just another question, after giving that grants, which command could I use to simply force a JOB to start, to break it and unbreak?

Comment: There is an awful lot of syntax to DBMS_SCHEDULER.  Is suggest you read the documentation instead of asking lots of questions on SO. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/schedover.htm#i1106753

Comment: Thanks for the shout out APC!  I forgot that post even existed.